# Query to check booking availability by comparing datetimes

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm designing a car booking system and I'm trying to write a query that will check whether a car is available. What I want the query to do in english is to check that the start hire and end hire selected which are stored in variables $mysql_startdate and $mysql_enddate do not overlap with any existing bookings.

I have checked that the variables in the query have the value that they should have so I'm guessing there is a problem with my syntax, most likely the last part.

Format of datetime variables:

$mysql_startdate = 2012-03-22 00:00
$mysql_enddate = 2012-03-23 00:00

I am getting no errors from mysql_error, the problem is that no results are displayed even if a car that is available is requested.

```
$query = "SELECT c.*,b.startHire,b.endHire FROM cars c JOIN bookings b WHERE c.currentBranch = '$pickUpLocation' AND NOT (b.startHire > '$mysql_enddate' OR b.endHire < '$mysql_startdate')";
```

The startHire and endHire fields in the database are set to datetime and have the format - 2012-03-02 00:00:00 etc.

Can you help me to identify the problem and amend the sql query?

Let me know if you need any further code/information.

Thank you!

Comment: On what are you joining cars and bookings? Is your query giving results if you leave the where condition?

Comment: Yes Im joining cars and bookings. If i leave out the WHERE condition, all of the car information is displayed along with startHire and endHire from bookings which is correct. So the problem is after the WHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
SELECT c.*, b.startHire, b.endHire 
FROM cars c JOIN bookings b 
WHERE c.currentBranch = '$pickUpLocation' 
AND NOT b.startHire between '$mysql_startdate' and '$mysql_enddate'
and not b.endHire between '$mysql_startdate' and '$mysql_enddate'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It's displaying the cars when I don't pick dates that overlap but when I do no results are coming back from the query when I need the cars that are available to be displayed :(

Comment: Could you give 2 examples - dates that work and dates that don't?

Comment: Existing booking =  2012-03-02 00:00:00 - 2012-03-06 00:00:00.
Dates that display cars - '2012-03-07 00:00:00' and '2012-03-08 00:00:00'.
Dates that display zero results - '2012-03-02 00:00:00' and '2012-03-08 00:00:00'
So basically if the dates overlap with the bookings, it is not displaying any cars rather than only filtering out the car that has been booked.

Comment: Now I understand your problem. Just a guess: Try an explicit join instead of implicit: `... FROM cars c INNER JOIN bookings b ON c.id = b.car_id WHERE ...` (Column names wher just a guess)

Comment: Right the query at the moment is - SELECT c.*, b.startHire, b.endHire FROM cars c INNER JOIN bookings b ON c.regNumber = b.regNumber WHERE c.currentBranch = '$pickUpLocation' AND NOT b.startHire BETWEEN '$mysql_startdate' AND '$mysql_enddate'AND NOT b.endHire BETWEEN '$mysql_startdate' AND '$mysql_enddate'";
For some reason it is not displaying anything when I select dates before the booked dates. However,if I select dates that overlap or are after the booked dates it is displaying the car that is booked.

Comment: So it is recognising the booked car, just displaying it instead of filtering it out and displaying the available cars. Bit confusing!